# SQL Server Error: XQuery [nodes()]: A node or set of nodes is required for 'nodes()'

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I was trying to pass my variables into the `nodes()` and `value()` methods, but some errors occurred:

```
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(50) = '/A/B/C',
        @node VARCHAR(20) = '@name',
        @result XML ='
        <A>
            <B>
                <C name='nameA'/>
            </B>
            <B>
                <C name='nameB'/>
            </B>
        </A>
        ' 

SELECT T.c.value('./sql:variable("@node")', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @result.nodes('sql:variable("@path")') T(c)
```

Raises the error:

> XQuery [nodes()]: A node or set of nodes is required for 'nodes()'

Also, when I use '/A/B/C' to replace `@path`, the error raised:

> XQuery [value()]: The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.

My goal is to get a table like:

```
|Name|
|NameA|
|NameB|
|···|
```

Comment: Please add your xml content.

Comment: Do you have a question? Also, it would be helpful to see what value you have for `@Result` and to also know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated that, thank you!

Comment: You can only pass a single node to `nodes` as a variable, you cannot pass a full path. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39164962/1048425) for some possible workarounds